# When I add an option to a select the select gets narrower

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

Inherited an app with a page that has a link that calls the javascript function addValueClick(), when I do this a dialog box pops up, I type in some text, and then the text gets put in the select box.  Every time a new option is added to the select it gets about 5 pixels narrower. I can't figure out why this is happening, but it only happens in IE7

Here is the javascript:

```
function addValueClick()
{
    var newValue = prompt("Please enter a new value.","");
    if (newValue != null && newValue != "")
    {
        var lst = document.getElementById("lstValues");
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.setAttribute("selected", "true");
        opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newValue));
        lst.appendChild(opt);
        updateBtns();
        copyValues();
    }
}

function copyValues()
{
    var frm = document.forms[0];
    var lst = frm.elements["lstValues"];
    var hid = frm.elements["hidValues"];
    var xml = "<root>";
    for (var i = 0; i < lst.options.length; i++)
    {
        xml += "<value seq_num=\"" + (i + 1) + "\">" +
          lst.options[i].text + "</value>";
    }
    xml += "</root>";
    hid.value = xml;
}

function updateBtns()
{
    var lst = document.getElementById("lstValues");
    var iSelected = lst.selectedIndex;
    var lnkEdit = document.getElementById("lnkEditValue");
    var lnkDelete = document.getElementById("lnkDeleteValue");
    var lnkUp = document.getElementById("lnkValueUp");
    var lnkDown = document.getElementById("lnkValueDown");
    if (iSelected == -1)
    {
        lnkEdit.style.visibility = "hidden";
        lnkDelete.style.visibility = "hidden";
        lnkUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
        lnkDown.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else
    {
        lnkEdit.style.visibility = "visible";
        lnkDelete.style.visibility = "visible";

        if (iSelected == 0)
            lnkUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
        else
            lnkUp.style.visibility = "visible";

        if (iSelected == lst.options.length - 1)
            lnkDown.style.visibility = "hidden";
        else
            lnkDown.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The HTML, it's actually ASP.NET.  All the listValueChanged() method does is call updateButtons() above.

```
<tr>
    <TD class=body vAlign=top noWrap align=right><b>Values:</TD>
    <TD class=body vAlign=top noWrap align=left><asp:ListBox id="lstValues" runat="server" onchange="lstValuesChange();" Rows="9" onselectedindexchanged="lstValues_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox></TD>
    <TD class=body vAlign=top noWrap align=left>
        <TABLE id="Table2" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="2" border="0">
            <TR>
                <TD noWrap>
                    <asp:HyperLink id="lnkAddValue" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:addValueClick();">Add</asp:HyperLink></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD noWrap>
                    <asp:HyperLink id="lnkEditValue" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:editValueClick();">Edit</asp:HyperLink></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD noWrap>
                    <asp:HyperLink id="lnkDeleteValue" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:deleteValueClick();">Delete</asp:HyperLink></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD noWrap>
                    <asp:HyperLink id="lnkValueUp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:valueUpClick();">Up</asp:HyperLink></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD noWrap>
                    <asp:HyperLink id="lnkValueDown" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:valueDownClick();">Down</asp:HyperLink></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: Hard to tell from just the JavaScript - do you have a set width defined on the `<select>` tag in CSS?

Comment: No, this is an old application written by someone else, there is very little in the way of CSS.

Comment: You can still try adding a style attribute to `asp:ListBox` and defining a static pixel width. Worth a shot.  `"style= width: 250px;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was where the Option was being added to the Select I changed it to the following and it works perfectly:

```
function addValueClick()
{
    var newValue = prompt("Please enter a new value.","");
    if (newValue != null && newValue != "")
    {
        var lst = document.getElementById("lstValues");
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.text = newValue;
        opt.value = newValue;
        try {
            lst.add(opt, null); // real browsers
        }
        catch (ex) {
            lst.add(opt); // IE
        }

        updateBtns();
        copyValues();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may have more to do with the html than the script.  What is the select contained in?  Based on the JS, I don't think there are any problems here.

Comment: It's in a table, I included it above.

Comment: Are there any widths defined on the html elements on the page?  Try definining widths for your tables, rows and columns.  And its the whole list that gets smaller, not the item in the list right?

Answer (score 0):

I know that adding options via `SelectElement.innerHTML = '...';` [fails in IE (bug 274)](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-274-dom-methods-on-select-lists.html).

But I don't know about adding options via .createElement() failing... although I'm not overly surprised.

You can use the JavaScript `new Option();` syntax to create them, I'm fairly certain that works without failure.